# Java - Displaying a Background by using Buffered Image

Tags: java, bufferedimage

Writing a little game here and I have ran into some issues. I can not for the life of me manage to display my buffered image.

I think I have everything in place but obviously something is wrong if the background is still black.

Game Class:

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private boolean running = false;
    private Thread thread;

    public static int WIDTH, HEIGHT;



public BufferedImage background = null;


// object handler
Handler handler;

Random rand = new Random();

private void init(){

    WIDTH = getWidth();
    HEIGHT = getHeight();
    BufferedImage background = new BufferedImage(0, 0, 0);
    try{
        background = ImageIO.read(new File("/Background.png"));

    }catch(IOException e){

    }

    handler = new Handler();


    public synchronized void start(){
        if(running)
            return;

        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run(){
        // Heat of the Game. Game Loop.
        init();
        this.requestFocus();
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int updates = 0;
        int frames = 0;
        while(running){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1){
                tick();
                updates++;
                delta--;
            }
            render();
            frames++;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames + " TICKS " + updates);
                frames = 0;
                updates = 0;
            }

        }

    }

    private void tick(){
        handler.tick();
    }
    private void render(){  
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    private void LoadImageBackground(BufferedImage image){
        int h = image.getHeight();
        int w = image.getWidth();   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Window(762,720, "BusyBee", new Game());
    }   
}
```

Window Class:

```
public class Window extends Game { 
    public Window(int w, int h, String title, Game game){

        game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w,h));
        game.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(w,h));
        game.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(w,h));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setIconImage(background);


        // starts the synchronized game start() method
        game.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: `JFrame.setImageIcon` sets the icon for the frame that appears on the top left side in the decoration of the frame. It doesn't set the backgound of the JFrame's content pane. See the JavaDoc for details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setIconImage-java.awt.Image-

Comment: AH! Thank you for that link. Could you tell me, am i in the correct area to add the background to the JFrame or should it be done from the Game class?

Comment: There is no `setBackgroundImage` in the `JFrame` class, you should think of replacing the content pane of the frame. Example: `frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(background));`

Comment: But since you have a canvas anyway I would suggest to paint the image on that canvas

Comment: That would mean i would have to rewrite the bufferedImage code in class Game to take the bufferedImage as a JLabel and then setContentPane taking in the newly created JLabel under the JFrame. Would i be correct?

Comment: It could work but I would recommend to set the `game` object as the content pane (instead adding it to the content pane) and paint the bg image on the canvas

Comment: Ah ha, Ok, thank you for igniting the light blub. I shall give that ago. Makes a lot more since. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have BufferedImageLoader, so I used the following code to load my image:

```
try {
    background = ImageIO.read(new File("/Background.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Don't forget to draw your image in render!

```
private void render(){  
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    // DRAW THE BACKGROUND!!
    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

Comment: Why should it be better to use `ImageIcon`?

Comment: Convenience.  I didn't have BufferedImageLoader and I could load ImageIcon in one line.  I will edit to use BufferedImage.

Comment: Then please load BufferedImage. I dont know BufferedImageLoader too but javax.imageio loads them as well

Comment: I tried it your way (see above). The image did not update to the screen.

Comment: @JamesOconnor Take out the extra declaration of BufferedImage.  You are loading the image into that local variable instead of the global.